# Getting error in executing OWLAPI

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create an ontology using owlapi in eclipse using owl-osgi-distribution 4.0.2 and getting an error of Noclassfound which is similar to the error as in the link

[Getting error in executing OWL API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459428/getting-error-in-executing-owl-api)

and as per the error  I was getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   
com/google/inject/Provider at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native  
Method) at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at    
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at   
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at 
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at 
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at 
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at 
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at test.main(test.java:18) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.Provider at 
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at 
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ... 25 more
```

With the answer in the link I understood that my owlapi files need to be added for which I referred at the following way to solve it.

http://www.jabenitez.com/2015/08/19/solucionando-el-error-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-comgoogleinjectprovider/

I did the entire above procedure and when ran the code

```
 package ontology;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.util.Set;

 import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
 import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.IRI;
 import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLAxiom;
 import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntology;
 import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
 import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;

 public class Owlapitutorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // load file
    File file = new File("F://Ankita//creatingOntology//ontofit.owl");

    // loading the ontology
    try {
        OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLOntology localOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);

        //getting all axioms    
        Set<OWLAxiom> axSet= localOntology.getAxioms();

        System.out.println(localOntology.getLogicalAxiomCount());

    } catch (OWLOntologyCreationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

After that my program gave me the following error

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   
org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.<clinit>  
(OWLAPIServiceLoaderModule.java:50)
at org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager.<clinit>(OWLManager.java:42)
at ontology.Owlapitutorial.main(Owlapitutorial.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

I did understand and verified that one of the dependency file org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.7: was missing in the lib folder of owlosgi which I downloaded and added into the build path making a new library.

I also created a new file in my folder F://Ankita//creatingOntology//ontofit.owl and ran the program and now I am getting a different error i.e.

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further    
details.
0
```

I have gone to StaticLoggerBinder site for further details and downloaded the zip file of SLF4J but I have no idea what am I supposed to do since there are many jar files in it.

Can anyone please help me.

Arc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SLF4J provides a common interface to several alternative logging systems, but you haven't included any of them in your project, so it is defaulting to the NOP logger implementation. If you want to implement more useful logging, you should include one of the alternatives suggested on the SLF4J page given in the error message (http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder), such as Log4J.

Alternatively you can safely ignore that message, but you won't get any logging information if things go wrong.