# Why I cant create an ontology?

Tags: java, owl, protege, owl-api

I am currently getting started with OWL. I believe that I have setted up the correct .jar for the OWL API. However, when I compile the code I get an error on the line:

```
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
```

The error says :

```
cannot access com.google.inject.Provider 
class file for com.google.inject.Provider not found
```

Any ideas on what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, you need more jars to be able to compile and run. The documentation clearly states, and I quote with emphasis mine: "In order to use the API in your own applications, you should download the latest binary release and ensure that **all of the jar files are in the application classpath**". https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation .

Comment: [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30459428/getting-error-in-executing-owl-api) maybe it helps. I think you're missing some dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use pom, be sure you use correct dependency as is written [here](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation#howto).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>owlapi-distribution</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you use jar file, as you exactly wrote, so be sure, you added it correct as is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)

Afterwards, be sure, you imported the correct package in your Class.
And also, be sure you downloaded all you need, like [that](https://github.com/owlcs/releases/blob/master/owlapi/3/owlapi-dependencypack-3.5.6.zip)

For start line in your question, you need that imports

```
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyManager;
```

And better, try to use maven as was written [here](https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/wiki/Documentation#javadoc)

Comment: The latest version is 5.1.10